# Editing Titanium 3.2.2GA Android SDK

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am building an application for Android and iOS using Titanium SDK 3.2.2GA which is free. I am using [Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer) for the development of the stuff related to audio in my application but this audio player provided by titanium is kind of incomplete for example, duration is not available in iOS and Android but the property exists.

So in order to add the functionality which is not currently present in this library, I edited the Titanium SDK for iOS from the path **(Library/Application\  Support/Titanium /mobilesdk/osx/3.2.2.GA /iphone/Classes)** but I am stuck when it comes to Android because the Android folder contains the precompiled classes in the form of .class files.

So, I was just wondering if anyone has a solution for it. All I want is to implement the fix mentioned in the following [commit](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/4428/files), to my existing Titanium SDK but when I goto **(Library/Application\  Support/Titanium /mobilesdk/osx/3.2.2.GA /android/modules/..)** all the files inside it are pre-compiled .class files.

TIA.

Comment: You should use a newer version, 3.2.2.GA is very outdated. At least go to 3.5.1.GA, but better is go to a more recent version

Comment: `ti sdk install 3.5.1.GA` should work

Comment: @RenePot That's what I did since 3.2.2.GA has a few problems so I upgraded to 5.0.1 but it still lacks the seek/setTime functionality for iOS (AudioPlayer Class)

Answer (score 0):

The 3.2.2.GA version of Titanium SDK is very old. As Shoaib mentioned above you should use a more recent version, for instance: 5.2.2.GA or the current stable 5.3.1.GA. However, if you need to use the 3.2.2.GA version for some special requirement, you must download the source code of SDK version, make the changes (apply the commit) and compile it, instructions available in: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Building+the+Titanium+SDK+From+Source

Comment: Thanks for the link, however now I am going ahead with 5.0.1.